# Return value of cell address in column to right or left of a given cell address

Tags: excel

I'm using the below formula to return the address of values from `sheet2` that match my value in `sheet1`:

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH(C18,Sheet2!C:C,0),3)
```

If the returned result in `sheet1` cell `E19` is (`sheet2`) `$c$8` (and not null), 
then I would like to find what value is in `sheet2` `$h$8`.

Comment: Sounds like you need `VLOOKUP` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest the formulas. Use the `Match` function to test whether the searched value exists.  If it does exist, then the false part of the `If` statement uses the `VLOOKUP` to find the corresponding value in column H.

```
=If(IsError(Match(C18,Sheet2!C:C,False)),"match not found",VLOOKUP(C18,Sheet2!C:H,6,False))
```

(untested, so double-check that I put the parentheses in the right spots)

With this approach, you can only do a left-to-right search, so for example you couldn't return a value in column A, by searching column C.  You could modify this approach using the `INDEX` function (which I know is possible) or possibly the `OFFSET` function.

Here is an example of finding a value in corresponding row of Column A, while searching column C, using the `Index` function (tested & verified):

`=INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH(C18,Sheet2!C:C,FALSE))`

You could add the error logic like:

`=If(IsError(Match(C18,Sheet2!C:C,False)),"N/A",INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH(C18,Sheet2!C:C,FALSE))`